# How to show colred red green diff patch?

Tags: diff, colordiff

I already generated a diff patch between 2 files: `diff file1 file2 > file3`
Does there a way to display properly the file3 path, in a colored way.
`cat file3` do the job but there's no colors.

Comment: What is a colored way? Are you just looking for [`colordiff`](https://www.colordiff.org/)? Or do you want syntax highlighting or something else?

Comment: in fact colerdiff is a wrapper for 'diff', diff command does already the job when I dont redirect the ouput to any file. I need a command from the file3, I can display a collred diff.
cat file3 do the job but ther's no colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colordiff` to read `file3`:

```
colordiff < file3
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I'm looking about.